# SSL remove support for TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA

Tags: ssl

I have this config inside my `/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf`

```
SSLProtocol             all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
SSLCompression          off
SSLSessionTickets       off
```

The problem is that I'm getting this weak cipher

```
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xa)   WEAK
```

I know that its equivalent name is `DES-CBC3-SHA`.
How can I remove this cipher from the above list? Notice that its not in `SSLCipherSuite` list

Comment: I suggest that the configuration you show is not the one which is actually active when accessing the site from outside. There might be a configuration specific to the server name you are using, there might be a reverse proxy (or  load balancer or WAF) in front of it with a different configuration or similar.

Comment: I really dont have much idea regarding this topic as I was just tasked to do this. We actually have 2 servers up and running. One server is using the above config while the other server has the TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA. Could it be that is the reason why its showing?

Comment: *"Could it be that is the reason why its showing?"* - maybe, maybe not. There is basically nothing known about your infrastructure except a small snippet from the configuration of one server and the information that there is at least another server involved.

Answer (score 0):

The weak cipher might be due to older components installed on that specific computer.

1. Do a Windows update (and reboot) to make sure the computer is updated with the latest patches / service packs as necessary.
2. Run (as administrator) the powershell command below to disable to weak cipher:
   Disable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"

More info in the Microsoft link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/tls/disable-tlsciphersuite?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Here is a how-to to disable weak versions of SSL/TLS Protocols on Windows Servers:
https://www.jorgebernhardt.com/disable-ssl-and-tls-on-winserv/